# dashed lines from pdf document

Tags: pdf

I am trying to infer the table structure from  [this document](http://www.accordiagolf.co.jp/file/pdf/news_20150410131436.pdf);

So far, I have identified the "re" operator and got most of the structure, but the dashed lines (such as the vertical line between the second and third column in the link) I can't seem to extract. They do not seem come from h/l/m operators.

The [pdf-spec](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) talks about a "line dash pattern", which seems to be what i am looking need, but as I understand it this is a parameter applied to a path, so presumably if I can get h/l/m operators my parser should identify these lines correctly.

Could someone please shed light on what I might be missing here? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't identify these "lines" is that they aren't lines. The dash pattern is produced by repeatedly placing image XObjects of a few pixels wide/high each to give the semblance of a dotted line.

Yes, that's a stupid way to do it - the better approach would be to do what you said and set the dash pattern in the current graphics state followed by some line drawing operations. That would have made the resulting page drawing code about ten times smaller :)

Comment: Here on my iPad the resolution and resampling is so abysmal, I actually see a gray gradient with some darker and lighter spots. Yup, no doubt about it, a bitmap. And indeed stupid--what PDF creator software eas used?

Comment: That would be Word in combination with Acrobat PDF Maker 6.0 on Windows. Now... Acrobat 6.0 has been outdated for quite a while of course :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - i know what to look out for now.  Guess there's no point asking why someone would create a document like this... cases like this just drive me up the wall!